# Determine the type of array as boolean result

Tags: typescript

I could not find exact answer for my problem, just want a way to determine something like

```
const numArray = [1,2,3,4];
const objArray = [{thing: value}, {thing: value}];

if (numArray typeof number[]) { console.log('This is an array of numbers.') }
if (objArray typeof object[]) { console.log('This is an array of objects.') }
```

Hope this explains even though I know is not correct as I am just learning.

Comment: You can check the type of the first item of the array and assume that all items have the same type or you can use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check all of them.

Comment: The question is about JavaScript, not about TypeScript.

Comment: You are conflating *compile-time* with *run-time*. Typescript types compile away, they do not exist at run time so you cannot query them as if they were Javascript values. You *can* (expensively, possibly unnecessarily) check the runtime type of  Javascript values using `arr.every(item => typeof item === 'number')`, but the *type* `number[]` does not exist then, and conversely since that check runs at runtime the result is opaque to the compiler (if you have, say, `any[]` and perform that check the compiler will not necessarily be smart enough to narrow the type to `number[]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the type of the first item of the array and assume that all items have the same type:

```js
const numArray = [1,2,3,4];
const objArray = [{thing: 'value'}, {thing: 'value'}];

if (typeof numArray[0] === 'number') {
  console.log('This is an array of numbers.');
}
```

Or you can use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check all of them:

```js
if (objArray.every((item) => typeof item === 'object')) {
  console.log('This is an array of objects.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof` to create a condition and use it with `Array.every()`

```
const isNumeric = (currentValue) => typeof currentValue == 'number';

const array1 = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

console.log(array1.every(isNumeric));
// expected output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it would be to use the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method of Arrays.

> tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.
> — *MDN docs*

We can check whether the condition in the callback to Array.every is satisfied for every element, that is whether every element is of the specified type.

```
 // takes as parameters the array to check in, the type to check for
 // returns whether all elements are of specified type

function allOfType(array, type) {
  return array.every((v) => typeof v === type);
}

console.log(allOfType(numArray, 'number'));
console.log(allOfType(objArray, 'object'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

- array of number : `numArray.every(i=>  typeof i == 'number')`
- array of object:  `numArray.every(i=>  typeof i == 'object')`